# DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo vs CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, datetime

I am trying to parse DateTime, with an exact format being accepted from client input.

Which one is better

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd-MMM-yyyy",
   DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

OR

```
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd-MMM-yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
```

Of course, this code is inside a common static method that is called wherever parsing of date is required.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the signature for `DateTime.TryParseExact`, it takes an [IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) as the third argument. Both `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` implement this interface, so you are actually calling the same method on `DateTime` in both cases.

Internally, if you use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, its [DateTimeFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx) property is called to get a `DateTimeFormatInfo` instance. If you use `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`, this is used directly. The `DateTimeFormatInfo` call will be *slightly* quicker as it has to perform less instructions, but this will be so marginal as to make no difference in (almost) all cases.

The main difference between the two approaches is the syntax. Use whichever one you find clearest.

Answer (score 3):

They will give the same results.
And it is very unlikely there would be any difference in performance.

So use whatever you think is most readable. My choice would be `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` for being slightly more to the point.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who like me ended up here from google, I found the following post by Matt Weber was quite useful to understand the implementation details:

http://badecho.com/2011/07/datetimeformatinfo-currentinfo-vs-cultureinfo-currentculture-datetimeformat-vs/

Let me quote most of the article here in case the link breaks at some point:

> **DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo**
>
> This will directly return another DateTimeFormatInfo instance that is
> set to the current culture. It does the following in order to do this:
>
> 1. Gets the CultureInfo from the current thread’s CurrentCulture property (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture). Note that when you are
>    accessing the current thread’s CurrentCulture property, you are
>    basically accessing the CultureInfo.CurrentCulture property (which
>    simply returns Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture).
> 2. Returns a direct reference to the date time format if the thread’s current culture instance is the base CultureInfo type itself, and not
>    a derivation. The DateTimeFormat property of the CultureInfo object
>    does not come into play here; instead, what we’re directly reading
>    from the CultureInfo object’s dateTimeInfo private field.
> 3. If the thread’s current culture instance has null assigned to its date time information field, then the CultureInfo‘s GetFormat method
>    is invoked, which returns a DateTimeFormatInfo instance which is then
>    returned.
> 4. If the current thread’s culture instance is actually an object type that derives from CultureInfo, then it will always make a call to
>    CultureInfo.GetFormat, and never read from the
>    CultureInfo.dateTimeInfo field directly.
>
> So, if you’re ever dealing with objects deriving from CultureInfo and
> setting the thread’s current culture to use them, be aware that you
> can modify the way the DateTimeFormatInfo is returned by overriding
> the CultureInfo’s GetFormat method.
>
> **DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo**
>
> This will return another DateTimeFormatInfo instance set to the
> culturally-insensitive culture. It does the following to do this:
>
> 1. If the current Application Domain already has created a culturally-insensitive DateTimeFormatInfo instance, this is returned.
> 2. Otherwise, a new instance is created using the public default constructor of DateTimeFormatInfo.
> 3. The Calendar exposed by new DateTimeFormatInfo instance is set to read only.
> 4. The new DateTimeFormatInfo instance itself is set to readonly, and then returned.
>
> So, unlike DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, the InvariantInfo property
> is initialized once per application domain, not per thread. Not a very
> big surprise, but may be important to know just in the event you’re
> doing anything adventurous and (most likely) irresponsible.
>
> **CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat**
>
> This will return a DateTimeFormatInfo object set to use the current
> culture. This is achieved by the following:
>
> 1. Because we’re accessing CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, the current thread’s CurrentCulture is used as the culture
>    (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture).
> 2. If the current thread’s culture instance already has a DateTimeFormatInfo instance initialized, that’ll be returned (i.e. if
>    the dateTimeInfo is not null, then that is returned).
> 3. Otherwise, a new DateTimeFormatInfo object is created by directly initializing a new DateTimeFormatInfo instance and passing the culture
>    data to the constructor.
> 4. The DateTimeFormatInfo instance is set to readonly.
> 5. A call is made to Thread.MemoryBarrier, and then the newly initialized DateTimeFormatInfo instance is assigned to the
>    dateTimeInfo field.
>
> **How Does CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat Relate to
> DateTimeFormat.CurrentInfo?**
>
> 1. The CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat property is what is responsible for actually initializing the DateTimeFormatInfo instance
>    that gets returned; calling DateTimeFormat.CurrentInfo results in a
>    call made to the culture’s GetFormat method, which itself will return
>    its own CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat property. So, regardless of where
>    you start, you seem to end up in the same place. Technically, calling
>    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat is more direct than calling
>    DateTimeFormat.CurrentInfo, which will end up calling just that.
> 2. Differences begin to arise when one starts talking about object types derived from CultureInfo. Let’s say we wish for our custom
>    CultureInfo class to return a DateTimeFormatInfo instance which is
>    modified in some fashion that differs from the norm. By override
>    CultureInfo.GetFormat, which is a virtual method, we can achieve this
>    for calls made to DateTimeFormat.CurrentInfo, which will call this
>    method.
> 3. However, because CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat is a static property, and because the instantiation of the DateTimeFormatInfo object is done
>    directly inside this property, there is no way to override this
>    behavior. Therefore, we can easily end up in a situation where
>    DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo returns a differently composed
>    DateTimeFormatInfo instance than what we get with
>    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat (assuming the current
>    culture is our custom culture class).
> 4. This makes our desire of ours one that may be impossible to fulfill (customizing the creation-related logic behind a custom
>    culture’s date time format). Hopefully no one out there needs to do
>    this.
>
> **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat**
>
> 1. This will return a culturally-insensitive DateTimeFormatInfo.
> 2. The invariant culture is created one per application domain, inside (indirectly) the static constructor of the CultureInfo class.
> 3. Once the invariant CultureInfo instance is created, the rest of the process of creating the DateTimeFormatInfo mirrors that of the
>    previous section.
>
> **How Does CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat Relate to
> DateTimeFormat.InvariantInfo?**
>
> 1. These two properties, unlike their CurrentCulture-ish brethren, are completely unrelated in how they initialize the DateTimeFormatInfo
>    instance that they return.
> 2. The DateTimeFormat.InvariantInfo property does not actually deal with culture at all. It simply initializes a new DateTimeFormatInfo
>    instance using that class’s default constructor.
> 3. Although their creation mechanisms are unlinked, they are similar in that one cannot exert any influence in the creation of these
>    constructs from derived classes, as far as I am aware.